# Maven Using Versions Maven Plugin on a branch

Tags: maven

I use `org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:1.2:use-latest-versions` to update my internal dependencies. In Normal development this works with no issues.

Now that the project is released we have branch development and we can not get the dependency to update as we would like.

Main development is 3.8-SNAPSHOT and Branch is 3.7-SNAPSHOT.

When used on the main development org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:1.2:use-latest-versions updates 3.8-SNAPSHOT to 3.8.x (x being the latest in NEXUS)

But when used on the branch develpoment `org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:1.2:use-latest-versions` updates *3.7-SNAPSHOT* to to *3.8.x*. So my question is how do I tell maven to update 3.7-SNAPSHOT to to 3.7.x? (x being the latest 3.7 in NEXUS)

Answer (score 0):

I used org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:1.3.1:set -DnewVersion=3.7.5 
-DartifactId=myArtifact -Dgroupid=myGroup